# How to print the hierarchical name of a signal given to a system-verilog task as parameter

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

This is the content of a task that is repeated for a lot of signals:

```
begin
      @(testbench.top.baud_rate_A);
            $display("Signal baud_rate_A changed: %t", $time);
failed = 1;  
end
```

I would like to optimize the code, and I wonder how could I keep the info message printed for each signal given to the task with accurately displaying the hierarchical name of the signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this in a macro with an argument that gets used as the signal name first, and then as a string

```
`define check(path, sig) begin \
      @(path.sig); \
      $display("Signal %s changed: %t", `"sig`", $time); \
      failed = 1; \
end
```

In your task

```
`check(testbench.top , baud_rate_A)
```